# stream firestore using logical AND in flutter, but its multiple

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a multiple filter using logical AND in `firestore`. I already try some code, I try using `arrayContainsAny` but it was OR logical, and after I read doc for `firestore` the only way to do AND logical is by using `isEqualTo`. Which is mean I need to make nest-if, after that I had to register the index and it so waste of time. Anybody know the solution for multiple filter using logical AND in `firestore`?

Answer (score 1):

> You can chain multiple equality operators (== or array-contains)
> methods to create more specific queries (logical AND).

```
final citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef
    .where("state", isEqualTo: "CO")
    .where("name", isEqualTo: "Denver");
```

This comes from the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

Comment: I have done this. My concern is it was a multiple filters so I need to check the user want to filter this data or not by using the if function. After using that need to register the index too. Just imagine I have 6 filter, many nest-if and I need to register it. It so wasting time

Comment: You only need to create composite index if you combine equality operator with inequality operators. And I don't understand why you need to do a lot of nested ifs. Present that code in that case. This post I made is how you construct logical AND queries.